# How to deal with comment on someones question asking for clarification when question is clear for others?

Tags: discussion, comments

The question of the questioner is already precise enough and obvious for a third person with some knowledge about the subject. Such a comment forces the OP to describe his problem further, instead of focusing on the solution. The commentator doesn't have any reputation on the `tag` yet.

I'm not sure:

- flagging the comment (what reason to give) appears to be to rough
- leaving the comment unanswered may be interpreted as a lack of interest by others
- commenting the comment includes the risk of being to chatty
- offering a bounty on the question of the OP?

PS: Please don't ask me for clarification now.

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Can you please make it more clear? o.O

Comment: _"commenting the comment includes the risk of being to chatty"_ - no, not in cases like this. Using comments to clarify things 100% matches their [official purpose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/165773)

Comment: Yes @gnat, the (main?) purpose of the comment is to ask for clarification. See "When should I comment?" [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: in the end -> comments can be flagged for removal is they are obsolete.

Comment: @hims056: Which part is unclear to you? -.-

Comment: @JensPiegsa - It was an irony comment. :-)

Comment: @hims056: Thank you for clarifying the obvious. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have to remember that future visitors for to the question are not going to be experts on specific topics, and may not speak/read English well.  They likely will come to the question because they have a similar question and found it via searching (SO search or Google or your search engine of choice).

So in that case, if the question is not clear for a non-expert, it is possible it could use further clarification just to avoid misunderstandings in the future.

Depending on how much more detail that can be added, it might be appropriate to edit the original question to restate the problem or add additional clarification.  Or a simple comment to the confused commenter might be all that is needed.

Comment: That's what we have to keep in mind for sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is clear to you, then you can just add an explaining comment.

> OP means that ... because ...

Answer (score 2):

If question is clear for you:

1. Comment @ the one who finds it unclear, with explanation.
2. If he will tell you why he found it unclear, edit the question to remove the reason of misunderstanding.

Comment: A simple, pragmatic solution!

Comment: @JensPiegsa basically what psubsee2003 wrote, but I posted few minutes earlier and gave an algorithm, not reasoning ;)